# Web Analytics Connector customization

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web-analytics-connector

I have to setup my WAC configuration including a IIF() function to detect if linkname contains the "%" char. In case of yes, I will include one AMPSCript var I am setting up in the context called "@alias", in case of no, I will include the own linkname value as it is at this moment. For that, I am askinf support to include  at the end of the "email_XtraLinkParameters" brand tag the following expression   -  ...`%%=IIF(IndexOf(linkname),'%')>0,@alias,AttributeValue('linkname'))`  - but is returning always empty avalue. Do you know what is wrong in the syntax ? I am testing this syntax in one Email and is working perfectly. Any other thing to consider? Perhaps some WAC feature enablement for using AMPScript in the brand tag ?

Comment: Hi Enrique, can you give some more detail about what you are trying to achieve by customizing your WAC? It sounds like you are wanting to append a new URL attribute to the end of your links based on if the link's "alias=" value contains a "%" character in it? What is the desired outcome of this - do you want to send the "alias=" value through to your website endpoint for tracking/analytics purposes?

Comment: Hi @CameronRobert

Comment: Hi @CameronRobert, this is exactly what I want to achieve. My HTML alias value is empty. WAC Brand Tag includes at the end the %%linkname%% personalization string value. If alias value is empty, %%linkname%% is populated with the url value. We are using a REdirectTo(@url) function in the URL, but WAC is not interpreting this function so is including this function not interpreted, so the final url contains something like that %%Redirecto()%% etc..So, when % is detected in the %%linkname%% value, just replace the value in the URL with the value stored in my AMPScript var called: alias.

Comment: Can you please update your question with some examples of the HTML code (including the %%RedirectTo()%% functions) and what the resulting link looks like - show what you mean by "WAC is not interpreting this function". Also please include an example of what you want the outcome to look like. Can you also confirm that you want to send these values to your website for analytics/tracking purposes - it's not for Click tracking/reporting in Salesforce?

Comment: My HTML code: <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@linkURL)=%%"  alias="" ><img data-assetid="85177" src="%%=v(@imageURL)=%%" alt="%%=v(@alttext)=%%" width="680" style="display: block;"></a>

Comment: The resulting URL: https://www.customerweb.com?utm_campaign=AT_UAT&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=20200127_962222_%%%3dRedirectTo(%40linkURL)%3d%%

Comment: My current WAC Brand Tag configuration: utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_content=%%=format(xtshortdate ,"yyyyMMdd")=%%_%%jobid%%_%%=linkname=%%

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by certain parameters not being available when the ampscript runs.
We had the same issue with Alias and had to give up after support confirmed.
Sorry can’t give any better advise:(
If someone has an update/workaround would also be greatful
Doug

Comment: Thanks @Doug for your response. Finally I got success implementing the AMPScript code with Salesforce Support help. And I would like to share with the community. The issue was basically related with the way of referencing the %%linkname%% personalization string (the alias) is a bit special in WAC. Here you have the solution: %%=IIF(IndexOf("%%linkname%%","%")>0,@alias,"%%linkname%%")=%%